# Laplace transform,what restriction do I have to take?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to use the Laplace transform, to find the solution of the equation $y''(t)-4y(t)=0, y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$.I found that: $Y(s)(s^2-4)=s+1$ .What restriction do I have to write for $s$ ?

Comment: First write $Y(s)=\frac{s+1}{s^2-4}$ and use a partial fraction decomposition so that you can easily apply the inverse Laplace transform to find the solution $y(t)$. The restriction on $s$ will be dictated by the existence of the Laplace transform of each piece of the solution.

Comment: I have found that $Y(s)=\frac{3}{4}e^{2t}+\frac{1}{4}e^{-2t}$.But,how can I find the restriction?I haven't understood yet..

Answer (score 2):

Whatever restriction there may be, it is based on the existence of the integral

$$y(t) = \frac1{i 2 \pi} \lim_{\sigma\to\infty}\int_{c-i \sigma}^{c+i \sigma} ds \, Y(s) \, e^{s t}$$

where $c$ is greater than the largest real part of any of the poles of $Y$.  In this case, then, when $t \gt 0$, $\Re{s} \lt c$, and when $t \lt 0$, $\Re{s} \gt c$.

Comment: Which integral did you consider at the differential equation I asked?

Comment: @evinda: this integral is the inverse Laplace transform you would use to find the solution $y(t)$ from the Laplace transform $Y(s)$.

Comment: I find that $Y(s)=\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{s-2}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{s+2}$ .Do you mean that I can find the restrictions,considering these: $\frac{1}{s-2}$ and $\frac{1}{s+2}$ ?

Comment: @evinda: yes.  The pole with the largest real part is $s=2$.  So, in the above integral, consider any $c \gt 2$.  When $t \lt 0$, the real part of $s$ must be less than $c$, and vice-versa when $t \lt 0$.  Because of this, $y(t) =0$ when $t \lt 0$ because there are no poles inside a closed contour in the complex plane including the line $Re{s}=c$.

Comment: Do I have to explain it,using the integral or is there also an other way?

Comment: @evinda: not aware of another way to explain it; if there is, it is sure to be equivalent to what I have said.

Comment: Isn't the only restriction $s>2$?or am I wrong?

Comment: You are not quite right.  The restriction depends on the sign of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is given by $$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt$$
Existance depends on the convergence of this improper integral. In your case we have 
$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{2t}\}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}e^{2t}dt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{(2-s)t}dt$$
Here if $s>2$ this integral will not converge. Similalrly 
$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{-2t}\}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}e^{-2t}dt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{(-2-s)t}dt$$
Here if $s<-2$ the integral will not converge. Taking both of these together you get your restriction on $s$.

Comment: So, from the first equation, we have that $s>2$ and from the second one that $s>-2$ .Right? And, because of the fact that both inequalities should be satisfied, we take that $s$ should be greater that 2?

Comment: No, from the second equation we $s<-2$ so taken together we want $s \notin [-2,2]$

Comment: And don't we also know that $s$ should be greater that $0$ ,when we use the Laplace transform? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Although $s>0$ is required for the existence of a lot of Laplace transforms it is not necessary as seen in your problem.

Comment: So,the only restriction is that it shouldn't belong here: $[-2,2]$ ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I looked again at the exercise.. Shouldn't $s$ be just greater than $2$ ?